# Tumblr theme dev: Square-75px photos for Photoset posts

Tags: api, templates, themes, tumblr

I am trying to use Tumblr's Theme API and just found out that for [Photoset posts](https://www.tumblr.com/privacy/consent?redirect=https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photoset-posts)
the variable `{PhotoURL-75sq}` (which should be inside `block:Photos` won't return a value.
It works ok for single photo posts but not for Photosets.

Also it seems that the picture itself gets generated but the API doesn't
return a proper value for example:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tumblr.com](http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lzvey54yzV1ro516ho2_250.jpg))</sub>

[image]

the images above where uploaded into a photoset post using tumblr control panel, and as you can see, by just replacing the end of the filename 250px image with `75sq` it shows up correctly (which means it was indeed generated).

http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lzvey54yzV1ro516ho2_75sq.jpg

but when using `{PhotoURL-75sq}', it won't return it's value.

```
{block:Photoset}
    <h1>{TimeAgo}</h1>
    <div class='slideshow'>
        {block:Photos}
            <img src='{PhotoURL-75sq}' alt>
        {/block:Photos}
    </div>
{/block:Photoset}
```

I am not sure if this is the right place to be asking for this but since their support refuses to help me by saying:

> Unfortunately, we can't provide technical support for HTML customizations. Given our large number of users, we just don't have the resources. Our apologies. If you'd like to learn more about HTML and CSS...

Where in this case I am thinking that or this is a bug or they simply renamed that variable when it's inside a Photoset without letting the developers know about it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, to start with, that's incorrect syntax for a photoset. `{block:Photoset}{Photoset-500}{/block:Photoset}` is what you want and you can obviously add more code around and below the photoset for the info, notes, etc. but THIS is your starting point. An iframe will be rendered with your photoset photos inside. You'll have to use Javascript to alter the contents of the iframe. I can give you an example, but it'll have to wait until after class. The Effector theme does this to create its hi-res slideshows for photosets.

Comment: Hi Ally, I'm afraid not, inside Photoset you can have another block called `Photos` which will return each one of the images individually in case you don't want to use their default Photoset widget. It's in the docs on the link mentioned and I am already using it, the only problem is with the 75px square photos.

Comment: Then `{PhotoURL-250}` or `{PhotoURL-500}` works? I was under the impression from your post that these did not work. In that case, you can still use the code I provided with some alterations. Regardless, you're going to have to use Javascript to process the URL to get the square URL because it is not provided in the documentation.

Comment: I updated my answer with the simpler code. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your head add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resizePhotosets(desiredSize)
{
    var setFrames = document.getElementsByClassName("photoset");
    if (setFrames != null)
    {
         for(var i = 0; i < setFrames.length; i++)
         {  
             var foundWindow = false;
             var frameWindow = null;

             while(!foundWindow)
             {
                 frameWindow = setFrames[i].contentWindow;
                 if (frameWindow != null)
                     foundWindow = true;
             } 

             var foundDoc = false;
             var frameDoc = null;

             while(!foundDoc)
             {
                 frameDoc = frameWindow.document;
                 if (frameDoc != null)
                     foundDoc = true;
             }

             if (foundDoc)
             { 
                 var photoRows = frameDoc.body.getElementsByClassName("photoset_row");
                 for (var j = 0; j < photoRows.length; j++)
                 {
                     photoRows[j].removeAttribute("style");
                     photoRows[j].style.display = "inline";
                     var photos = photoRows[j].getElementsByTagName("img");
                     for(var k = 0; k < photos.length; k++)
                     {
                         photos[k].style.width = desiredSize.substring(0, desiredSize.lastIndexOf('sq')) + 'px';
                         var source = photos[k].src;
                         var pos1 = source.lastIndexOf('_');
                         var pos2 = source.lastIndexOf('.');
                         photos[k].src = source.substring(0, pos1 + 1) + desiredSize + source.substring(pos2);
                     }
                }    
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


</script>
```

And then call it from your `body` tag like this: `<body onload="resizePhotosets('75sq')">`

The script does the following...

1. When the document has loaded, check if there are photoset frames on the page. If there are photoset frames on the page, continue. Otherwise, do nothing.
2. For each photoset frame, wait for the frame window and frame document to load.
3. As soon as the frame document has loaded, grab all of the photoset rows.
4. For each photoset row, clear the styling and set the display to inline.
5. Next, grab all of the photoset photos.
6. For each photo, set the image source to the desired size parameter.

Obviously, you can do whatever you want as far as styling goes in steps 4 and 6, but this was just a simple way to render all of the photoset photos at 75px and put them in a continuous line. If you have any questions, feel free to ask. I've tested it in my sandbox Tumblr and it does work.

**ETA:** I was not aware that `{PhotoURL-250}` worked inside of the photoset block, but it does. In that case, here is some simpler code:

```
{block:Photos}
<img src="{PhotoURL-250}" class="photoset-image" />
{/block:Photos}
<script type="text/javascript">
var photos = document.getElementsByClassName("photoset-image");
for(var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++)
{
    photos[i].style.width = '75px';
    var source = photos[i].src;
    var pos1 = source.lastIndexOf('_');
    var pos2 = source.lastIndexOf('.');
    photos[i].src = source.substring(0, pos1 + 1) + '75sq' + source.substring(pos2);
}
</script>
```

All this is doing is taking the URL provided and replacing it with the 75px square one.

Comment: great, thanks Ally, I agree this might be the better method to use it right now. I was just disappointed since this is clearly a bug on themes API and they refuse to listen to the developers about it :/ also it seems {PhotoURL-100} doesn't work..but the others work fine...anyway, thanks a lot for your elaborated response.

Comment: I don't know how much tumblr updated their stuff, but now every file might be on a different subdomain - 36.media.tumblr, 41.media.tumblr and etc so this will only work if you get lucky and the 75sq is stored on the same subdomain. Though the 75sq theme code in photosets doesn't work to this day...

Answer (score 1):

I was a little concerned about the browser unnecessarily loading the 250px images, so I did it a little differently.  Of course, I know almost nothing about javascript, so, fwiw:

Somewhere in the head or body (where it won't be repeated):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var img_75sq = function(imgTag, urlFor250px)
    {
       var urlFor75px = urlFor250px.replace('_250.jpg', '_75sq.jpg');
       var newImgTag = imgTag.replace('SRC', 'src="' + urlFor75px + '"');
       document.write(newImgTag);
    }
  </script>
```

And then:

```
    {block:Photoset}
       {block:Photos}
           <script type="text/javascript">
             img_75sq('<img id="..." style="..." SRC>', '{PhotoURL-250}');
           </script>
       {/block:Photos}
    {/block:Photoset}
```

This way the browser never sees 250px img tags.  The simplicity also suits my novice DOM/JS skills. :)