# Tumblr photoset custom width?

Tags: iframe, size, tumblr

I'm trying to get Tumblr's photosets to appear 640px wide.

I'm modifying [CATCHING ELEPHANT](http://safe.txmblr.com/theme/preview/7285) for my blog http://assemblyradio.tumblr.com/

I'm making the whole posts section of the theme wider.However, I can't seem to get photo sets to appear 640px wide.

I would like the sets to show up as Tumblr intended with their fancy layout, because they look great. Therefore this solution is not what I'm looking for:
[Change default photoset size on tumblr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530132/change-default-photoset-size-on-tumblr)

I have tried java script from here:
[Tumblr theme dev: Square-75px photos for Photoset posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513061/tumblr-theme-dev-square-75px-photos-for-photoset-posts)

and here:
[Change default photoset size on tumblr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530132/change-default-photoset-size-on-tumblr)

The second script sort of worked but the images are cropped off =(

If I add some custom CSS I can get the iframe to be 640px wide, but then the height does not adjust accordingly!

Everytime I think I figure it out on Chrome's web developer tool, I can't seem to get the code right in Tumblr's custome CSS. I thought using this selector gadget [[How can I get the CSS Selector in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500572/how-can-i-get-the-css-selector-in-chrome])
 could help me target exactly what CSS I should be editing (to see if that could help) but it can't tell me the path to the element, maybe because it's an iframe.

Does anyone know how to to get custom photoset width?
Or how to get an iframe height to adjust automatically?
Or how to find a complicated path to a class?

Any help would be much appreciated. I just want to see my cute kittens. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Tumblr's limitations had also been annoying me, so I wrote a jQuery plugin for a fully responsive Photoset layout that uses Tumblr's style. It also includes extra information (that can be toggled on/off) for EXIF and caption data on each photo.

https://github.com/PixelUnion/Extended-Tumblr-Photoset

Comment: Hi graygilmore!

Thanks for your quick responce =)

I did come across this plugin on my search for answers. 
I'm just a bit confused though. I have never used something like this before. 

How do I download the Requirements/how do i install them?
-jQuery v1.7.0 http://jquery.com/
-imagesLoaded jQuery Plugin https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Does the j.query version have to be 1.7? There only seems to be 17.1 and 17.2.

Also, my theme doesn't seem to have a body end tag. huh? 

I would really like to give this a try though- it may be my only hope!

Comment: ignore what I said about not having a </body> - I did something funny with my code. It's back now

Comment: You already have the latest version of jQuery in your theme, so no worries there. You'll need to download imagesLoaded https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded and the CSS from the plugin and then upload those files through Tumblr's uploader: http://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file

Once you have those, you'll need to added them to your theme file by editing the HTML in the customize screen.